# Python chr() equivalent to Swift

Tags: python, swift, unicode, utf-8

I don't have much experience with Unicode. My code produces different results in Python and Swift. Converting back and forth between byte arrays works in Python but makes the value blow up in Swift. Please have a look at those minimal examples:

Python:

```
finalBytes = [116, 24, 173, 213, 236, 238, 5, 32, 0]

myString = ""
for i in range(len(finalBytes)):
    myString += chr( finalBytes[i] );

print(myString)
print(len(myString))            #9

#turn back to byte array
testString = [ord(c) for c in myString]
print(testString)
print(len(testString))          #9, working
```

Swift:

```
import UIKit

let finalBytes = [116, 24, 173, 213, 236, 238, 5, 32, 0]

var myString = ""
for i in 0..<finalBytes.count {
    myString.append( Character(UnicodeScalar( finalBytes[i] )!))
}

print(myString)               //[116, 24, 173, 213, 236, 238, 5, 32, 0]
print(myString.count)         //9

let data = Data(myString.utf8)
let data_8 = [UInt8](data)
print(data_8)                 //[116, 24, 194, 173, 195, 149, 195, 172, 195, 174, 5, 32, 0]
print(data_8.count)           //13, is longer and differs in content
```

As you can see, the array stays intact in Python but turns into something different in Swift. `[24]` becomes `[24, 194]` and from there it gets worse. The three final bytes are good again.

I'd be thankful about a brief explanation as to what I encounter here or how I could fix this so Swift behaves like Python.

Comment: the bytes in swift are different, if you put an array of bytes in swift and python, the results will be different, the same case if you use java or other language

Comment: The code is not doing the same thing. The Swift example has a UTF-8 conversion step, but the Python does not.

Comment: So is there any way to make those two behave the same way?